# Как узнать, на каком диске установлена система?

Tags: c++

Итак, мне нужно узнать на каком диске установлена ОС. То есть, если у меня установлена система на C, то при запуске программы должно написаться то, что системный диск - С. Как это сделать на C++?

```
int main()
{
//code here
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/810281/5669174

Comment: @Mike, спасибо. Обязательно попробую этот способ.